# merging stats for domain.com/ and domain.com/index.php in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics now and it has the annoying feature of considering `domain.com/` and `domain.com/index.php` different items.

Is there a filter setting where I can instruct GA to merge the stats for these two items into one? It's stupid to have 20% of the homepage traffic showing up as `/index.php` rather than on the root.

Thank you!

Comment: Try the [Web Apps SE site](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: try asking this in the web apps or the webmasters stackexchange sites.  (click the stack exchange icon on top to navigate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a Filter on your profile.

Do this by navigating to account settings for your profile, then click 'Add Filter'

On the filter page, you'll need to configure it to do a Search & Replace operation on Request URIs, from /index.php to /

Here's an example of how you might configure that:

[image]

It's important to note that this filter is not retroactive; i.e., your past data will remain the same.